# Query not working as intended in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

In order to get  entries from a certain period of time ( Last week, last month) i have the following code in my Controller:

```
$data=Pedido::where([
                ['sitio_id','=',$idSitio],['fechaPedido','>=','CURDATE()-INTERVAl '.$rango.' DAY']
                ])
        ->latest('fechaPedido')
        ->get();

        echo json_encode($data);
```

now, when i execute it in my aplication, it returns all the entries in the Table "Pedidos", regardless of the  day interval i give it to it. I.E The site had no new entries in Pedidos since 24 days, so by week (7 days) it should return null.

Though when I ran a similar SQL query as below against my datqbase, it worked perfectly.

```
select * from `pedido` where (`sitio_d` = 1 and `fechaPedido` >= CURDATE()-INTERVAl 7 DAY) order by `fechaPedido` desc
```

When i run it in the PHPMyAdmin, it returns an empty result, and if i change the interval there, it gives me the correct output.

But in the web app, it always returns all the entries in the table, regardless of the interval.

Tried working around with it using DB::raw, but it threw an empty result, regardless of the date.

Is there a reason of why this its not working? Or a way to check the raw SQL laravel its sending to the database?

Im Using Laravel 5.4, and MySql

Comment: What do you get if you do `dd(Pedido::where([
                ['sitio_id','=',$idSitio],['fechaPedido','>=','CURDATE()-INTERVAl '.$rango.' DAY']
                ])
        ->latest('fechaPedido')
        ->toSql());

Comment: It returns "select * from `pedido` where (`sitio_id` = ? and `fechaPedido` >= ?) order by `fechaPedido` desc".  So, thats the raw query. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine the reason your query isn't working correctly is because you need to escape `'CURDATE()-INTERVAl '.$rango.' DAY'`.

You can either use `DB::raw()`:

```
$data =  Pedido::where('sitio_id', $idSitio)
    ->where('fechaPedido', '>=', DB::raw('CURDATE()-INTERVAl ' . $rango . ' DAY'))
    ->latest('fechaPedido')
    ->get();
```

`whereRaw`:

```
$data =  Pedido::where('sitio_id', $idSitio)
    ->whereRaw('fechaPedido >= CURDATE()-INTERVAl ' . $rango . ' DAY')
    ->latest('fechaPedido')
    ->get();
```

Or even just use a carbon instance to pass the date

```
$data =  Pedido::where('sitio_id', $idSitio)
    ->where('fechaPedido', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays($rango)->startOfDay())
    ->latest('fechaPedido')
    ->get();
```

Also, Eloquent will return a collection in this case so you can do `$data->toJson()` instead of `json_encode($data)`.

Furthermore, if you're just going to `return` the json from the `Route` / Controller method you can just do `return $data;` and Laravel will convert it for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This works with no problems. Also, ¿Is there a benefit of using $data->toJson() rather than json_encode() ?

Comment: @BrunoGutierrez I would say the only benefit is that it is chainable, apart from that, no, there isn't any extra benefit as it's just using `json_encode` behind the scenes.

Comment: @BrunoGutierrez Please be aware that using `db::raw()` and `db::whereRaw()` puts you in scope for SQL Injection vulnerabilities.  Make sure that any input you use in such a case is strictly cleaned.  In this case, this would do: `whereRaw( 'fechaPedido >= CURDATE()-INTERVAL ' . (int) $rango . ' DAY')`.  For this reason I would suggest using the last example: it uses prepared queries and is not vulnerable to SQL injection.  Also, the use of `Carbon` filters the user input anyway.